# Does InDesign have a "bitmap copy" function to rasterize in place?

Tags: adobe-indesign, workflow, rasterization

Inkscape has a function "Make a bitmap copy" that converts a selection of items in a document into a raster image, in place.

Is there an equivalent function available in Adobe InDesign?

What I am trying to achieve is to replace a complex vector image, which takes a long time to render in an exported PDF, by a rasterized render that loads much faster. I know how to do this manually by exporting, re-importing and positioning, but I would prefer a more straightforward workflow, as offered by Inkscape.

Actually using Inkscape is not an option in my case.

I have searched the web with several descriptions of the problem, to no avail so far.

Comment: Not out of the box I think. But one could write a script to copy selection, open Photoshop, create new document at a certain ppi, paste graphics, select all, copy merged, paste at correct position in InDesign, delete original selection. Our perhaps you can simply rasterize using InDesign's api. I don't know.

Comment: I don't believe so either. I've always done it manually... edit original, copy, paste in Photoshop, save. Relink frame in IDD to the new .psd. The scale/position should be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### No

You would have to rasterize artwork outside ID and import again.